# Why use Bower with Meteor

Tags: meteor, bower

Ok, this is probably a very lame question, but given that Meteor has packages support, what is the advantage of having bower on top of it?

Comment: Bower lets you install and update libraries you use into your project like Jquery, Angular, various angular modules etc... You can install it with a simple command instead having to go to the website, download the package, unzip it and put it in the project, bower does this for you.

Comment: Yes but how is this different from "meteor install jquery"?

Comment: oh well I think meteor gets packages from https://atmospherejs.com/ while bower has its own repositories with different libraries

Comment: IMHO its only a preference thing, I don't prefer using bower with Meteor, can find almost everything @ atmospherejs.com

Comment: Preference is what I thought indeed. Thanks for confirming.

Answer (score 0):

It is definitely not always the case that meteor packages repository (atomsphere) have updated packages that match the original library version, whereas with bower you can normally install the original JS lib and hence will be more easy to control and update.

Eg. Hubspot drop library:

implementation of lib on atmosphere:

Lib version from atmosphere wrapped for meteor was at time of writing implemented for drop version 0.5.4
https://github.com/thesaucecode/meteor-drop

Original lib was at time of writing at version 1.4.1
https://github.com/HubSpot/drop